# DITMatlab: How to calculate hysteresis for experimental data set?

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing

I got an experimental data set [that looks more or less like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2Zu.png).

I need to determine how big the hysteresis loop is, aka if I look at two points with the same capacity (Y axis), whats the maximum distance between said points (X axis).

The issue is, data points arent located on the same Y value, aka I cant just find max X and min X for every Y and subtract them - that'd be too easy :^)
I figured I can use convex hull (convhull) to calculate the outer envelope of the set, but then I realised, it will only work for the convex part, not the concaved part, but I guess I can divide my data set into smaller subsets and find a sum of them... or something.

And then, assuming I have the data set thats only the outer outline of the data set, I need to calculate distances between left and right border ([as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgZ8b.png)), but then again, thats just data set of X and Y, and Id need to find the point where green line crosses outer rim

So here are the questions:

Is there a matlab procedure that calculates the outer outline of data set, that works with the concaved part - kinda like convhull, but better?

Assuming I have the outline data set, is there an easy way to calculate secant line of data set, like shown on second picture??

Thanks for any advice, hope I made what I have in mind clear enough - english isnt my first language

Benji

EDIT 1: Or perhaps there is an easier (?) way to determine, which points form biggest outline? Like...  group points into (duh) groups, lets say, those near 20%, 30%, 40%... and then pick two randomly (or brute force pick all possible pairs), one for top boundary, other for bot boundary, and then calculate area of polygon formed this way? Then, select set of points resulting in polygon with biggest area?

EDIT 2: Ooor I could group them like I thought I would before, and then work on only two groups at a time. Find convex hull for two groups, then for two next groups, and when Im done with all the groups, Id only need to find points common to all the group, and find a global hull :D Yeah, that might work :D